# Date formatting in Java to a specific format

Tags: java, date, java-time

The date I fetched from an open API is `2021-04-28`. I want to format it in this way: `4/28/2021`. Below is the method I tried:

```java
public String formatDateFetchedFromAPI(String transDate) {
    LocalDate apiDate = LocalDate.parse(transDate, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
    String actualDate = formatter.format(apiDate);
    return actualDate;
}
```

This throws an error saying:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-04-28' could not be parsed at index 4

If the data that I pull from open API is `20210426` then this method works just fine and returns `4/28/2021`.

Comment: The Date you are trying to parse simply isn't in the basic iso format. I recommend checking the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html (have a look at **Predefined Formatters**) - You are trying to parse a date with "ISO Local Date" format as far as i can see.

Comment: Thanks. This link u shared helped me to find the solution instead of using basic iso i used iso loca date. Thanks again!

Comment: What is that "open API" that is spoken of (as the OP has left the building somebody else might to to chime in)?

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are written in camelCase, so no underscores are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date looks like an [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE) and not [`BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE), so instead you can just use

```java
LocalDate apiDate = LocalDate.parse(transDate);
```

without `DateTimeFormatter`, because `LocalDate.parse` by default uses `ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.